# Why does typeid print true?

Tags: c++, c++11, typeid

I have a two test cases for `std::is_same()` and `typeid()`.

case 1: For `std::is_same()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_same<int, volatile int>::value << '\n'; // false
}
```

**Output :**

```
false
```

Its gives the correct output.

case 2: For `typeid()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

#define CMP_TYPE(a, b)  cout<<(typeid(a) == typeid(b)) << endl;

int main()
{
    cout << std::boolalpha;
    CMP_TYPE(int, volatile int)
}
```

**Output :**

```
true
```

Why does typeid print true?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: From Mat's link: "In all cases, cv-qualifiers are ignored by `typeid` (that is, `typeid(T) == typeid(const T))`". This behaviour is expected.

Comment: It's not "wrong". It's defined to work differently. If you rephrase your question, it might actually be an interesting one.

Comment: To answer the unasked question, `typeid` was designed to extract runtime type information, hence the behaviour.

Comment: @PasserBy Adding to that, its intended usage is RTTI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

> In all cases, cv-qualifiers are ignored by typeid (that is, `typeid(T) == typeid(const T)`)

Which means that I can get this work:

```
#define TYPECMP(T, U) (typeid(T) == typeid(U))
assert(TYPECMP(int, const int));
assert(TYPECMP(int, volatile int));
assert(TYPECMP(int, const volatile int));
assert(TYPECMP(const int, volatile int));
```

Comment: No you can't, because that's not a `constexpr` value ;)

Comment: @Quentin How do I improve? Does replacing `static_assert` with `assert` work?

Comment: Yes. Protip: you can use [an online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) to test stuff quickly :)

Comment: @Quentin It's not Godbolt this time. Interesting. I have a terminal emulator and Vim + GCC, though.